# flutter issue : tabBarView issue in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

wrong data showing in tabview.

In my app my all tab created dynamic, Here I have issue this when I am first clicking on "VEG PIZZA" then immediate I changed my Tab on "NEW LAUNCH" then my "veg pizza" data is showing on "New launch" tabview.

I dont know how to fix it.

[image]

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

import '../../../Utils/GlobalColor/global_color.dart';
import '../../../Utils/GlobalTextStyles/global_text_styles.dart';
import '../BlocPages/CubitPage/MenuListCubit/menu_list_cubit.dart';
import '../BlocPages/CubitPage/MenuListCubit/menu_list_state.dart';
import '../SkeletonsPage/skeleton.dart';
import '../Utils/ConstantsPages/constants.dart';
import '../Utils/ConstantsPages/toast_page.dart';
import 'Components/pizza_card.dart';

class VegPizzaPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final menuCategoryData;

  const VegPizzaPage({Key? key, this.menuCategoryData}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<VegPizzaPage> createState() => _VegPizzaPageState();
}

class _VegPizzaPageState extends State<VegPizzaPage> {
  bool isVeg = false;
  bool isNonVeg = false;

  bool showBtn = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    print("menuCategoryData:: ${widget.menuCategoryData}");
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      myCategoryId = widget.menuCategoryData["Id"];
     });
  }


  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    print("didChangeDependencies");
    BlocProvider.of<MenuListCubit>(context)
        .menuList(widget.menuCategoryData["Id"], outletId);
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<MenuListCubit, MenuListState>(
      listener: (context, menuListState) {
        if (menuListState is MenuListCodeSentState) {
          // myPizza.clear();
          // myPizza.addAll(menuListState.menuListData);
        }
        if (menuListState is MenuListErrorState) {
          showToastWithBlackColor(menuListState.error.toString());
        }
      },
      builder: (context, menuListState) {
        if (menuListState is MenuListLoadingState) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SliderSkeleton(
                  aspectRatio: 16 / 7.5,
                ),
                SliderSkeleton(
                  aspectRatio: 16 / 7.5,
                ),
                SliderSkeleton(
                  aspectRatio: 16 / 7.5,
                ),
                SliderSkeleton(
                  aspectRatio: 16 / 7.5,
                ),
                SliderSkeleton(
                  aspectRatio: 16 / 7.5,
                ),
                SliderSkeleton(
                  aspectRatio: 16 / 7.5,
                ),
                SliderSkeleton(
                  aspectRatio: 16 / 7.5,
                ),
                SliderSkeleton(
                  aspectRatio: 16 / 7.5,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        } else if (menuListState is MenuListCodeSentState) {
          return Container(
            color: MyColor.bgLightColor,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                widget.menuCategoryData["Id"] == 106 ||
                        widget.menuCategoryData["Id"] ==
                            105
                    ? Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        height: 52,
                        child: Center(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                top: 0, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 0),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                InkWell(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      isVeg = !isVeg;
                                      isNonVeg =
                                          isNonVeg ? !isNonVeg : isNonVeg;
                                      print("isNonVeg" + isNonVeg.toString());
                                      print("isVeg" + isVeg.toString());
                                      // myPizza.clear();
                                      for (int i = 0;
                                          i < menuListState.menuListData.length;
                                          i++) {
                                        if (isVeg) {
                                          if (menuListState.menuListData[i]
                                                  ["IsVeg"] ==
                                              true) {
                                            // myPizza.add(
                                            //     menuListState.menuListData[i]);
                                          }
                                          print("here");
                                        } else if (isNonVeg) {
                                          if (menuListState.menuListData[i]
                                                  ["IsVeg"] ==
                                              false) {
                                            // myPizza.add(
                                            //     menuListState.menuListData[i]);
                                          }
                                          print("here1");
                                        } else {
                                          print("here2");
                                          // myPizza.add(
                                          //     menuListState.menuListData[i]);
                                        }
                                      }
                                      // log(myPizza.length.toString());
                                    });
                                  },
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Container(
                                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                                        height: 16,
                                        width: 16,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(1.5),
                                          border: Border.all(
                                              width: 2,
                                              color: MyColor.greenColor),
                                          // color:MyColor.blueColor
                                        ),
                                        child: Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                                          child: isVeg
                                              ? Icon(
                                                  Icons.check_outlined,
                                                  size: 12.0,
                                                  color: MyColor.greenColor,
                                                )
                                              : Icon(
                                                  Icons.check_outlined,
                                                  size: 12.0,
                                                  color: MyColor.bgLightColor,
                                                ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(width: 6),
                                      Text(
                                        'VEG ONLY',
                                        style: textStyleWith10500(
                                            MyColor.blackColor),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 18,
                                ),
                                InkWell(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      isNonVeg = !isNonVeg;
                                      isVeg = isVeg ? !isVeg : isVeg;
                                      print("isNonVeg" + isNonVeg.toString());
                                      print("isVeg" + isVeg.toString());
                                      // myPizza.clear();
                                      for (int i = 0;
                                          i < menuListState.menuListData.length;
                                          i++) {
                                        if (isVeg) {
                                          if (menuListState.menuListData[i]
                                                  ["IsVeg"] ==
                                              true) {
                                            // myPizza.add(
                                            //     menuListState.menuListData[i]);
                                          }
                                          print("here..");
                                        } else if (isNonVeg) {
                                          if (menuListState.menuListData[i]
                                                  ["IsVeg"] ==
                                              false) {
                                            // myPizza.add(
                                            //     menuListState.menuListData[i]);
                                          }
                                          print("here1..");
                                        } else {
                                          print("here2..");
                                          // myPizza.add(
                                          //     menuListState.menuListData[i]);
                                        }
                                      }
                                      // log(myPizza.length.toString());
                                    });
                                  },
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Container(
                                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                                        height: 16,
                                        width: 16,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(1.5),
                                          border: Border.all(
                                              width: 2,
                                              color: MyColor.primaryRedColor),
                                          // color:MyColor.blueColor
                                        ),
                                        child: Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                                          child: isNonVeg
                                              ? Icon(
                                                  Icons.check_outlined,
                                                  size: 12.0,
                                                  color:
                                                      MyColor.primaryRedColor,
                                                )
                                              : Icon(
                                                  Icons.check_outlined,
                                                  size: 12.0,
                                                  color: MyColor.bgLightColor,
                                                ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        width: 6,
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        'NON-VEG ONLY',
                                        style: textStyleWith10500(
                                            MyColor.blackColor),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ) : Container(),
                cards(menuListState.menuListData),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
        if (menuListState is MenuListErrorState) {
          return Center(
            child: Text("${menuListState.error}"),
          );
        }
        return Container();
      },
    );
  }
}

extension WidgetExtension on _VegPizzaPageState {
  cards(myPizza) {
    return myPizza.length == 0
        ? Center(
            child: Text("No records found!"),
          )
        : Padding(
            padding:  EdgeInsets.only(top: widget.menuCategoryData["Id"] == 106 ||
                widget.menuCategoryData["Id"] ==
                    105 ? 52 : 0.0),
            child: ListView.builder(
                physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                padding:  EdgeInsets.only(top: widget.menuCategoryData["Id"] == 106 ||
                    widget.menuCategoryData["Id"] ==
                        105 ? 11 : 20.0, bottom: 20),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: myPizza.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: index == 0 ? 0 : 12,
                    ),
                    child: PizzaCard(
                      myPizza: myPizza[index],
                    ),
                  );
                }),
          );
  }
}
```